# Stopping CSS animation after certain time with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on this animation and I was wondering if there is a way to stop it from running and direct me to another page (say google.com) after 5 seconds?

The idea is to make this animation some sort of a loader, so when the user has finished browsing one page and click on a button, they will be directed to this page with animation and after 5 seconds they will be directed again to a different page.

```css
body {
  background: #373940;
}

.socket {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.hex-brick {
  background: #ABF8FF;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.h2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.h3 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.gel {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.center-gel {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.c1 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c2 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c3 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c4 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c5 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c6 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c7 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c8 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c9 {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c10 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c11 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c12 {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c13 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c14 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c15 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c16 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c17 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c18 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c19 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c20 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c21 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c22 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c23 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c24 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c25 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c26 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c27 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c28 {
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c29 {
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c30 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c31 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c32 {
  margin-left: -111px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c33 {
  margin-left: 65px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c34 {
  margin-left: 65px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c35 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c36 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c37 {
  margin-left: 81px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.r1 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}

.r2 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

.r3 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
}

.r1>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}

.r2>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

.r3>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01);
    transform: scale(0.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
  50% {
    background: #90BBBF;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01);
    transform: scale(0.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
  50% {
    background: #389CA6;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="socket">
  <div class="gel center-gel">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c1 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c2 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c3 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c4 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c5 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c6 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gel c7 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gel c8 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c9 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c10 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c11 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c12 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c13 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c14 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c15 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c16 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c17 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c18 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c19 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c20 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c21 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c22 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c23 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c24 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c25 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c26 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c28 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c29 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c30 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c31 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c32 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c33 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c34 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c35 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c36 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c37 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not with CSS. It's not a scripting language.

Comment: Side note, you have two sets of body tags in your example

Comment: You can probably use some clever animation duration and iteration counts to get it to stop after the desired duration, but I believe @isherwood is correct-- you probably need to leverage JS to force a redirect.

Comment: How can I do it with Jquery?

Comment: Revise your question to ask that. Update your title, post body, and tags accordingly. The animation is irrelevant since you're just asking how to redirect pages (which has already been asked and answered, btw).

Comment: Hi @dawn there was a [similar question asked here about redirecting using JS and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't have the redirect method, but javascript does. This code has a click event listener that after 5 seconds, redirects the user.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-continue")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      location.href = "https://google.com";
   },5000);
});



<button class="btn-continue" type="button">Continue</button>
```

Or just wait 5 seconds and redirect without button click:

```
   setTimeout(function(){
      location.href = "https://google.com";
   },5000);
```

Comment: @dawn that is no problem. If it works, please feel free to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use scripting. Using jQuery:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

 setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "whereYouWantToGoNext.html"; }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myButton">Redirect</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this *without* javascript would be to use your animation as an overlay instead of as its  own separate page, and hide it after a certain amount of time (or number of iterations) instead of redirecting.

(I've done this here somewhat lazily with a wrapper container, leaving the rest of your css intact; you could probably do better by modifying the existing animations to end on their own.)

```css
.container {
  background: #373940;
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  animation: hideMe 9s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation: hideMe 9s linear forwards;
  pointer-events: none;

}


@keyframes hideMe {

    99% {opacity: 1}
    100% {opacity:0; display: none}
}

.socket {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.hex-brick {
  background: #ABF8FF;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.h2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.h3 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.gel {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.center-gel {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.c1 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c2 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c3 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c4 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c5 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c6 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c7 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c8 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c9 {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c10 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c11 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c12 {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c13 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c14 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c15 {
  margin-left: -47px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c16 {
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c17 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c18 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c19 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c20 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c21 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c22 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: -99px;
}

.c23 {
  margin-left: -63px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c24 {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c25 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c26 {
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: 69px;
}

.c27 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c28 {
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c29 {
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c30 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c31 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c32 {
  margin-left: -111px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.c33 {
  margin-left: 65px;
  margin-top: -43px;
}

.c34 {
  margin-left: 65px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.c35 {
  margin-left: -79px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

.c36 {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: -71px;
}

.c37 {
  margin-left: 81px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.r1 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}

.r2 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

.r3 {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
}

.r1>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}

.r2>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

.r3>.hex-brick {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01);
    transform: scale(0.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
  50% {
    background: #90BBBF;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01);
    transform: scale(0.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
  50% {
    background: #389CA6;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ABF8FF;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="socket">
  <div class="gel center-gel">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c1 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c2 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c3 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c4 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c5 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c6 r1">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gel c7 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gel c8 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c9 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c10 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c11 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c12 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c13 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c14 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c15 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c16 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c17 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c18 r2">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c19 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c20 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c21 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c22 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c23 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c24 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c25 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c26 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c28 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c29 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c30 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c31 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c32 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c33 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c34 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c35 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c36 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gel c37 r3">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<div>
This is the page content you wanted to be "redirected" to.
</div>
```